# Build formula with multiple functions in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft

I need to build a formula in Excel which will calculate the following:

= ((5.3 - value in specific cell) divided by 5.3)) X 100

I tried this formula:

`=5.3-I70/5.3*100`    (where I70 is the specific cell)

sample using  (5.3-2.43) (divided by 5.3) X 100 = 54.15

My formula did not work.

Please advise, thank you

Comment: How did it not work? based on what you wrote it seems like you are missing  parantheses (excel abides by order of operation) so: `=(5.3-I70)/5.3*100`

Comment: furthermore, you need to make sure I70 contains numbers and not text...

Comment: `=5.3-I70/5.3*100` calculates I70/5.3 first, then I70/5.3*100.